# Displaying symbols properly in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, symbology

I opened one point shapefile with ArcGIS 10.2 and I want to change the symbol of it.

When I click on the symbol, the ESRI symbols in the **Symbol Selector** don't show properly, but like "!" and "&".

What can I do to show them properly?

[image: error in symbols]

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing the error, as it seems to be a visualization problem.

Comment: sorry, how can i upload the screenshot?

Comment: Click the "edit" text to edit your question and click the Image button to insert an image.

Comment: i sent the picture, did you receive it??

Comment: Does this happen within any blank map document for any point layer?  Has this always happen, any major changes to your computer?

Comment: i tried many shapes, and it was the same problem.i didn't any major changes to my computer,

Comment: may be i have to reinstall the ARC GIS 10.2??

Comment: is the problem related to my windows fonts?

Comment: Are you using v10.2 or v10.2.2?  If 10.2, did you install the service pack?

Comment: i am using 10.2,

Comment: i did'nt remember, i installed it 3 months ago.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this question from Esri's help forum [Symbols not showing Correctly.](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/114241)

The answer that appeared to work is the following"

> ArcGIS Symbols are defined making use of installed fonts. If the installation was complete, you will have TrueType font libraries TTF installed into C:\Windows\Fonts directory.
>
> For ArcGIS 10.x should be 73 named esri_1.ttf --> esri_837.ttf.  These font/symbol libraries will have a Title associated with them, e.g. esri_1.tif is Titled: ESRI Cartography  and esri_837.ttf is Titled: ESRI ERS Operations S1.
>
> If they are missing, or can't be read the system will substitute a replacement from an available font/symbol library on the system.  A common one that causes issues for folks is the esri_40.ttf library titled: ESRI North--those are the North arrow symbols that don't exist on most systems and sometime are not embedded into PDF printouts from ArcMap -- the arrow is missing and a weird character is shown instead.
>
> So, take a moment to look in C:\Windows\Fonts and check that the ESRI fonts are present, and also that in the Properties --> Security tab Users are able to Read & Execute, and Read the fonts/symbols. Be sure to check a few of them.  If not present, try the repair install. If present and incorrect permissions, should be able to assign correctly (or rerun the installation "Run as Administrator").